# How to properly filter date in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi i'm using library(carData) - MplsStops and i want to filter all events that took place in 2017 july, neighborhood Cedar Riverside, St. Anthony East, Downtown West and then arrange them by lat and long.

date format looks like that: **2017-01-01 00:00:42**

i'm using  dplyr

for now i'm trying to make this code work:

```
MplsStops %>% 
  filter(neighborhood=="Cedar Riverside" | neighborhood =="St. Anthony East" | neighborhood =="Downtown West") %>%
  filter(date==2017-07) %>%
  arrange(lat,long)
```

i think there is some problem with `date==` could anyone give me any tips how to make it work

Comment: `date==2017-07` is going to test whether the date is equal to 2017 - 7, i.e. whether the date column is equal to the number 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to change the `==` to `%in%` and `format` the 'date' to do the `==`

```
library(dplyr)
library(carData)
MplsStops %>%
  filter(neighborhood %in% c("Cedar Riverside", "St. Anthony East", 
          "Downtown West")) %>%
  filter(format(as.Date(date), "%Y-%m") == "2017-07") %>%
  arrange(lat, long)
#  idNum                date    problem   MDC citationIssued personSearch vehicleSearch         preRace            race gender
#1 17-264432 2017-07-14 22:07:37    traffic   MDC             NO           NO            NO         Unknown           Black   Male
#2 17-274061 2017-07-21 13:17:05 suspicious   MDC            YES           NO            NO Native American Native American Female
#3 17-252658 2017-07-06 23:29:22    traffic   MDC             NO           NO            NO         Unknown    East African   Male
#4 17-250572 2017-07-05 18:31:16 suspicious   MDC           <NA>           NO            NO           Black           Black   Male
#5 17-269530 2017-07-18 17:03:38    traffic other           <NA>         <NA>          <NA>            <NA>            <NA>   <NA>
#6 17-277463 2017-07-23 22:05:45    traffic   MDC             NO           NO
NO           Black           Black   Male
#...
#       lat      long policePrecinct    neighborhood
#1 44.96437 -93.24308              1 Cedar Riverside
#2 44.96440 -93.23357              1 Cedar Riverside
#3 44.96466 -93.23616              1 Cedar Riverside
#4 44.96497 -93.23492              1 Cedar Riverside
#5 44.96497 -93.23492              1 Cedar Riverside
#6 44.96497 -93.23492              1 Cedar Riverside
#...
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option might be to use the lubridate package that has many useful functions to work with dates.

```
library(dplyr)
library(carData)

MplsStops %>%
  filter(neighborhood %in% c("Cedar Riverside", "St. Anthony East", 
          "Downtown West")) %>%
  # I first filter for all dates that were in 2017 and then for all 7th months
  filter( lubridate::year(date) == 2017 & lubridate::month(date) == 7 ) %>%
  arrange(lat, long)
```